# Detect when Scrollview Scrolling not tableview scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a scrollview inside tableview (tableview's header) and I want to call this action when scroll finish:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let pageNumber = round(bookScrollView.contentOffset.x / bookScrollView.frame.size.width)
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)

    print("scroll")
}
```

when I scroll bookScrollView nothing happen, but when table view scroll this function run.

How I detect when bookScrollView scroll and run function?

thanks

Comment: You need to  set delegate of scrollView like this `self.scrollView.delegate = self`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, you can define, scrollOfTable, or you can also define TAG property. identify and only scroll when scrollview comes in, not tableview.

You also need to check, if your scrollView is setting delegate

```
self.vsScrollView.delegate = self

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == scrollOfTable {

    }
    else if scrollView == scrollOfScrollView {

    }
    else {
        //something else
    }

}
```